# PyQt5 User accessing

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.9

We have a university system developed by pyqt5 and python, in the login interface, the instructor can log in by the id and pass, but after login, we have another interface to show the courses of the instructor based on the input id that was from previous interface, the problem that the interface of the courses does not show the courses for the instructor( the id is not accessible to next interface).

I noticed that each interface is not updated when we do action, what is the command to let interfaces' action linked together?

This is the code:

```py
class InstructorLogin(QDialog):
    
    def __init__(self):
       
        super(InstructorLogin, self).__init__()
        loadUi("NewInstructorLogin.ui",self)
        

        self.LoginInst.clicked.connect(self.gotoAfterInstLogin)
        self.ExitLoginInst.clicked.connect(self.gotoMainExit1)
        self.PmuPassInstButton.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        
     #For the password 
       
    
    def gotoAfterInstLogin(self):
        global f
        global user
        user = self.PmuIDInstButton.text()
        password = self.PmuPassInstButton.text()
        # print(user)

        if len(user)==0 or len(password)==0:
            self.InvalidPassLab.setText("Please input all fields.")

        else:
            conn = sqlite3.connect("Cognito.db")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            query = 'SELECT Password FROM Instructor WHERE Instructor_id =\''+user+"\'"
            cur.execute(query)
            result_pass = cur.fetchone()[0] #to compare password 

            if result_pass == password:
                
                self.gotoInstructorLoginAbulBashar()
                #####end of noorsol
            else:
                self.InvalidPassLab.setText("Invalid username or password")
       

            
            

    def gotoMainExit1(self):
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()-1)
#Remove comment later
    def gotoInstructorLoginAbulBashar(self):
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+15)
       

    # def user_getter(self):
    #     return user  
       

    
########################################################################################################################
class ChooseCourseInst(QMainWindow):
    global user

    
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChooseCourseInst, self).__init__()
        
        #self.afterObj = AfterInstructorLogin()
        self.afterInstructorLogin = AfterInstructorLogin()
        
        
        loadUi("CoursesChosenInt.ui",self)  
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+4)
        self.exitabulbashar.clicked.connect(self.gotoexitabulbashar)
        #self.InstServButton.clicked.connect(self.gotoInstServButton)
        self.coursesreq.activated.connect(self.gotoInstServButton)
        #self.courses(user)

        #print(user)
    def courses(self):
        self.instructorLogin = InstructorLogin()
        
        conn = sqlite3.connect("Cognito.db")
        
        query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Course_name FROM Course WHERE Instructor_id =\''+self.instructorLogin.gotoAfterInstLogin(user)+"\'"

        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute(query)
        final_result = [i[0] for i in cur.fetchall()]

        for i in range(len(final_result)):
            self.coursesreq.addItem(final_result[i])
         
        
    def gotoexitabulbashar(self):
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()-16)

    def gotoInstServButton(self):
        self.chosencourse = self.coursesreq.currentText() 
        self.afterInstructorLogin.labeltest.setText(self.chosencourse)
        self.afterInstructorLogin.diplayInfo()
        #self.afterInstructorLogin.labeltest.show()
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()-11)
```

I tried to let the user id as global variable, and create object and call it from the previous class, it shows User not defined, but the i put it inside function and i call that function in another class, it is defined but the courses empty so i expect to know how to refresh interfaces to let the change in first interface reflected in the second

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand where the problem actually is, as your code is clearly missing other components (the fact that you have to skip about 15 pages is a clear hint). Unfortunately, it seems clear that the actual problem is the terrible way the whole UI has been structured, probably following a youtube tutorial (some "hala") that is known to provide a plethora of terrible suggestions and bad practices, including using arbitrary references to the main stacked widget pages, or even adding QDialog to it. Even if you are able to fix the current problem, that code will most certainly->

Comment: -> cause further issues in the future, so I strongly suggest you to completely disregard that tutorial (if you've been following it), and try to find others that are *actually* valid (starting from [here]), and rebuild the UI structure completely, as right now it's completely unreliable, and any attempt to fix it will just create more issues.